# What is the encoding of db name in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the encoding of the database name if I create a db by the query "CREATE DATABASE xxx" in sql server 2012? I found it's not allowed to explicitly define the db name as a unicode string as N'xxx' in this statement.

Comment: strings are not names. In places where SQL Server expects a *name*, giving it a *string* won't work. (Of course, in places it expects a *string*, if you give it a *name* and that resolves to e.g. a column whose contents is a *string*, that can, often, work). There aren't many places where SQL Server gives you the option of providing *either* of a name or a string.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Create a database with a dynamic name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a database with dynamic database name in sql server 2005](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202257/create-a-database-with-dynamic-database-name-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
CREATE DATABASE [any unicode string up to 128 characters]
```

or

```
CREATE DATABASE "any unicode string up to 128 characters"
```

More on **Database Identifiers**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx

**EDIT:**

Here is an example:

```
CREATE DATABASE [ネット最前線]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'ネット最前線_Data', FILENAME = N'C:\temp\ネット最前線_Data.mdf' , SIZE = 209920KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 16384KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'ネット最前線_Log', FILENAME = N'C:\temp\ネット最前線_log.ldf' , SIZE = 768KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

Comment: _The collation of an identifier depends on the level at which it is defined._
If I understand the document correctly, it's impossible to define identifiers in unicode explicitly by using unicode literals. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Collation determines how SQL Server will sort character columns not what type of characters they will store.  `NCHAR` columns can handle unicode chars regardless of collation.  The info regarding a database is stored on the `master` database.  Check `master.databases` **name** column, it's defined as `nvarchar(128)`.  You can specify `CREATE DATABASE [ネット最前線]` to create a database named `ネット最前線`, for example.

Comment: Collation also determines how SQL Server compares character values (case sensitive vs. insensitive).